# webpack-dev-server renders all js files, but throws 404 on load

Tags: javascript, webpack-dev-server

My environment was working perfectly, but suddenly this behaviour appeared.

The page includes some scripts 'images.js' 'polyfill.js' 'vendor.js'

When running the webpack server, everything starts nicely (green 'rendered' messages). But when opening the page (index.html is available), on loading the referenced scripts, I just get 404 in the output window.

It seems to me that there were build errors on server startup, but there is no error output. Is there any way to look 'deeper' into what the server makes on startup?

Comment: Check to see where your generated JavaScript file is in your folders and ensure you're pointing to the correct directory within your index file.

Comment: That's part of what I don't understand really. According to the config, the output should be in a 'dist' folder
  output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        publicPath: '',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    }
But just running the server, no files appear there. So I believe, it just holds them in memory.

Comment: Does anyone have some insights of the webpack server? Where it holds the rendered js files, and where I could see some more logging info?

Comment: Looks like none. Well... earlier I thought it would just hold the files in memory. But now I think it is supposed to put them in the 'dist' folder (configured in webpack.config.js) but there is nothing.

So again - can anyone tell me where to find more output/logging info? There is no error running 'webpack-dev-server' ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the guys on Github, I could solve it finally. Turned out that there is a difference in the behaviour running the webpack server on Windows 10 (where everything works for my collegues) and Windows Server 2008 (which I am using). Setting the 'publicPath' in the webserver config to http://localhost:3000/ solved it.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/702

Comment: I have similar issue running webpack build on Win Server 2008. Resulted bundle .js is different and not working in opposite to Win 10 build.